# Incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct ListNode’

Tags: c, linked-list

I try to create dynamically an array of the structure ListNodes where I would like to store each node.
I get this message and I don`t know what should be the problem [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8N8C.png)

```
struct ListNode {
  int val;
  struct ListNode *next;
  };

struct ListNode* middleNode(struct ListNode* head){

int count=0;
int i=0;
struct ListNode* p=head;
struct ListNode* array = (struct ListNode*)malloc(100*sizeof(struct ListNode));
while(head!=NULL)
{
    array[i]= head;
    head=head->next;
    count++;
    i++;
}
    
  return array[i/2];
    free(array);
```

}

This is a solution in C++ : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtXbH.png)

Comment: `array[i]` is not a pointer. It is a `struct ListNode`.

Comment: You cannot `free(array)` after `return`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks for the reply. How can you store in this case in the array a certain node?

Comment: `return array[i/2]` seems nonsense. And you don't return a pointer with that. Turn warnings of your compile on.

Comment: Store the array in a node?? Or store the node in the array? And then: make a copy of the node or place a pointer to the node in the array?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I think i should place a pointer to a node inside the array in order to be able to return it.

Comment: Then declare as `struct ListNode **array` to make it a pointer to an array of pointers.

Comment: And allocate as `malloc(100*sizeof(struct ListNode *))` to allocate the size of pointers, not of structs.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  Thank you, now it is working!

Comment: You don't actually have to allocate an array for this. Just traverse another `ListNode*` at half the pace as you're traversing `head`. By the time `head` is `NULL` your other node will be in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in the comments, you could write your function as:

```
struct ListNode* middleNode(struct ListNode* head)
{
    int i=0;
    struct ListNode *retval;
    struct ListNode **array = malloc(100*sizeof(struct ListNode *));
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        array[i]= head;
        head=head->next;
        i++;
    }
    retval= array[i/2];
    free(array);
    return retval;
}
```